# XMLHttpRequest sending XML to PHP server

Tags: php, javascript, xml, post, xmlhttprequest

I was wondering if I could send some data from my client-side (2d application using HTML5's canvas) to the server-side in the XML format?

I tried something like this:

```
function send_xml_data_to_server(xml, url) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.open("POST", url, true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
    xmlhttp.send(xml);

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        callback_response_from_server(xmlhttp);
    }
}
```

Because in the informations that I must send to the server-side, it contains a few texts and it doesn't seem to work quite right with the the MIME:

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
```

But when I'm on the server-side I checked $_POST but there is nothing inside it, the same for $_REQUEST.

So, at the end, I was wondering if it is even possible to send XML data to the server-side PHP using XMLHttpRequest?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong on the client side, but `$_POST` contains a parsed set of key/value pairs, but that's not what you're sending to the server. Use something like this:

```
file_get_contents('php://input');
```

Then you can parse the string using SimpleXML or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

$_POST will be empty if you do not send data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

did you try this?

```
$xml = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

This way you will capture data in raw format and interpret it according to used mime type.